# What's the best way to use bucktail jigs to catch Butterfly Peacock bass?

Tags: fishing, rivers

I would like to fish for Butterfly Peacock bass with some [bucktail jigs](https://www.onthewater.com/versatile-bucktail-jig), but I haven't been able to find information on the best way to rig my line to have a successful setup.

I live in Florida and am fishing in a river that is around 20-30ft deep where I am. I've heard that the average size of these fish here is around 5 lb. I have a 6'6" light power Ugly Stik spinning rod and a 3000 Penn Pursuit reel with 10lb braided line.

How do I use/rig a bucktail jig in this situation and what size jig should I use?

Comment: Those are very powerful fish. If the average is 5lbs, then you'd expect to see larger ones. That might be a lot for that rod/reel/line combo.